# MVC load values submited as get

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, get, submit, html-helper

I'm implementing a page list with one search panel which submits one GET form.

I have three fields, one to search a for a field name, created with a `@Html.TextBox`, the other two with extensions created for me.

The thing is that when I submit the form and the page reloads to show the results, the only field that loads the value again is the `@Html.TextBox`, even if I didn't set any value on `value` parameter.

Below is the code implementing these search fields, any idea how the `TextBox` extension works to have this behavior?

```
@Html.TextBox("s.Name", null, new { @class = "text", @maxlength = "100" })
@Html.Date("s.Birthdate", null, new { @class = "datetime" })
@Html.SearchBoolean("s.IsPlayer")
```

Answer (score 0):

The source code for HtmlHelpers is [here](http://aspnetwebstack.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#src/System.Web.Mvc/Html/InputExtensions.cs)

If you look into code for generating `input` elements, which is used by `Html.TextBox` extension you will see this piece of code:

```
string attemptedValue = (string)htmlHelper.GetModelStateValue(fullName, typeof(string));
tagBuilder.MergeAttribute("value", attemptedValue ?? ((useViewData) ? htmlHelper.EvalString(fullName, format) : valueParameter), isExplicitValue);
```

The `GetModelStateValue` will search for the value of the field in the model passed into the view. So if you want to not show any value, you should just assign this field in the model a `null` value.